Smart card auth to a website via a certificate
I need help with authenticating to the website using a certificate that is extracted from a smart card in Kotlin or Java (on android 10)
So far I managed to extract the certificate from a smart card via APDU commands (the smart card is an ISO7816 standard). The certificate I extract has the attribute enhanced key usage Client Authentication (Proves your identity to the remote computer). It is extracted without the private key (to my understanding that is not possible).
However when I try to authenticate the website using this certificate, i get a 401: Unauthorized.
On Windows, this was pretty easy, you import the certificate in the keystore and its auto-imported with the private key, and this does not seem possible on android.
The site I'm trying to access is
https://api.sandbox.suf.poreskaupravars.org/api/v3/sdc/token
And the code I'm using
fun OkHttpClientWithCustomTrust(rootCert: X509Certificate, intermediateCert: X509Certificate,cert: X509Certificate): OkHttpClient {
    // Create a KeyStore that will hold the trusted certificates
val trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()).apply {
load(null, null)
setCertificateEntry("root", rootCert)
setCertificateEntry("intermediate", intermediateCert)
setCertificateEntry("cert",cert)
    }
// Create a TrustManager that trusts certificates in the trustStore
val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).apply {
init(trustStore) // 
} val aliases = trustStore.aliases()
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        val alias = aliases.nextElement()
        val certificate = trustStore.getCertificate(alias)
        if (certificate is X509Certificate) {
            val certType = when {
 certificate.subjectDN == certificate.issuerDN -> "Root Certificate"
 certificate.issuerDN.toString().contains("CN=") -> "Intermediate Certificate"
 else -> "End Entity Certificate"
 }
 Log.i("KeyStoreCertificate", "Alias: $alias, Type: $certType, Subject: ${certificate.subjectDN}, Issuer: ${certificate.issuerDN}")
 }
 }
    val trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.trustManagers // 
val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
 sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, SecureRandom())    
 val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory // Add an interceptor to force HTTP/1.1 usage
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
 .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager)
 .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)) // Force HTTP/1.1
.build()    
return client
}
fun CertificateDataAsync(certificate: X509Certificate, rootCert: X509Certificate, intermediateCert: X509Certificate) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
try {
            // Configure OkHttpClient with custom trust
val certList: List<X509Certificate> = listOf(rootCert, intermediateCert)
            val client = OkHttpClientWithCertHeader(certificate)            
            val request = Request.Builder()
 .url("https://api.sandbox.suf.poreskaupravars.org/api/v3/sdc/token")
 .get()
 .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
 .build()           
  val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                // Handle the response in the background thread
val responseBody = response.body?.string()
 withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
// Switch to the main thread to update the UI
Log.i("mTLS", "Response: $responseBody")
                }
} else {
 withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
Log.e("mTLS", "Authentication failed: ${response.code}")
                }
}
 } catch (e: Exception) {
 withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
Log.e("mTLS", "Error: ${e.message}")
            }
}
    }
}

From what I can tell using wireshark, the pubkey is sent but i still get 401. What am I missing here ?
How do I prove the ownership of the private key ?

What you are missing is that the certificate is just the public part, for an authentication you need to make use of the private key saved inside the smartcard. As the key is usually non-exportable you have to use the provided crypto methods for signing data inside the card and integrate that into the TLS handshake. The common J2SE  way would be implementing a PKCS#11 module loaded into Java but I am not sure if that way is possible on Android.

I have tried doing that, in  short there are commands where you can sign the hash of the certificate. You open a session via APDU, verify pin for the applet, set security enviroment and send the hash of the certificate to sign using sha256/512 (at least you gain a result back in hex and it decompiles in a certificate but there's no difference between it and the original one.
There is a way to implement PKCS#11 in android, but i'd rather not do that if its possible.
